# regex works in idle but not script

Tags: python, regex, python-idle

I'm using regex to find data elements in json files. I've defined 5 patterns.

```
from pathlib import Path                # path, iterdir
import fileinput                        # read file input
import re                               # regular expressions
import os

def main():
    mainList = []                                           # the list of elements to populate
    p1 = re.compile('\s*(\[|{),')                           # pattern: open group              e.g., '     {'
    p2 = re.compile('\s*(\]|}),?')                          # pattern: close group             e.g., '     }'
    p3 = re.compile('\s*".*": (\[|{)')                      # pattern: element, no value       e.g., '  "lnccodes": ['
    p4 = re.compile('\s*".*": (".*"|[^[{]*),?')             # pattern: element & value         e.g., '  "abnormal": false,'
    p5 = re.compile('\s*".*"')                              # pattern: value only (rare; lab)  e.g., '  "urn:cl:ien:60:205:72"'
    p = Path(os.getcwd())                                   # create a path

    for file in p.glob('lab' + '*' + '.json'):              # inner loop through files to read elements and values
        infile = open(file.name, 'r')                           # open file
        start = False                                           # initialize start
        lineNumber = 0
        for line in infile:                                     # for each line in the selected file
            lineNumber = lineNumber + 1
            if start:                                           # if we've gotten to the data in the file
                splitLine = line.split('"')                     # get parsed array of parts
                if re.fullmatch(p4, line):                      # test most common match first --  this is element & value
                    element = splitLine[1]
                    if splitLine[2].strip() == ':':             # if not string, get value from 
                        value = splitLine[3]
                    else:
                        value = splitLine[2].split(':')         # remove ':' from values
                    mainList.append((element, value, file.name, lineNumber))
                    continue                                    # once a match is found & processed, get the next line
                elif re.fullmatch(p1, line):
                    continue
                elif re.fullmatch(p2, line):
                    continue
                elif re.fullmatch(p3, line):
                    element = splitLine[1]
                    continue
                elif re.fullmatch(p5, line):
                    value = splitLine[1]
                    mainList.append((element, value, file.name, lineNumber))
                    continue
            else:
                if "[" in line:                                             # look for beginning of data
                    start = True                                            # indicate it has started
                    element = None                                       # initialize element
                    infile.readline()                                       # start has one [ and one {
                    lineNumber = lineNumber + 1                             # so we skip the { artificially

        infile.close()
        for k in mainList:
            print(k)
main()
```

All patterns work consistently in IDLE.

#4 works consistently in a script; #2 works sometimes (no leading spaces). Adding the raw flag didn't seem to have any effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you creating `line` in exactly the same way in both attempts?

Comment: This code is buggy: `p5 = re.compile(r'\s*".*"')` will match `"some value1": "value 2"` completely (and so will p3 and p4). Maybe that's what's wrong?

Comment: Also, uh, if you're trying to json, [there's a module for that](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Comment: Kevin, Yes, 'line' is coming from the same place.
WorldSEnder, I'm doing the tests in order & using 'continue' to avoid extra matches, but the problem is not too many matches; it's not enough.
NightShadeQueen, I was thinking this was pretty simple. Maybe that's next.

Bart, 
No, there are no line breaks within the quotes.
In case there's (intermittently) one in front, I tried 
 p2 = re.compile(r'\n?\s*(\]|}),?')
But it didn't change anything.

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? That way others can reproduce it. Right now, there's little very little to go on.

Comment: Agree with @NightShadeQueen - don't use regexes to parse JSON! That is the problem, regex is completely the wrong approach here. Use the `json` module instead. It will be *much* easier and 100% reliable. https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: For testing and posting purposes, infile should be a list of lines included with the code.  The code that processes a file (after `infile = open(file.name, 'r')`) should be in a separate function.

Comment: I a puzzled as the difference between running with Idle and without. Do you have more that one version of Python installed on your machine?  Is it possible that Idle is running with a different version than you are using directly?

Comment: No, Terry, that was the original point of the question. I can't fathom it. I'm an analyst, not a developer, so I was trying to do this with the most basic tools possible. Given this odd behavior, though, I have been playing with the json package (thanks, @NightShadeQueen), and it's easier than I'd feared, but now I'm grappling with variable scope in recursive function calls. Which I may have to post as another question.